# Anime with a robot attached to a boys back that protects him

Tags: story-identification, anime

I can’t remember the name of the anime (or manga) where the main character is a boy who has a robot thing attached to his back that protects him whenever it senses danger.

I remember one scene where he went to a well known assassin and the assassin was able to put a pen/fork/knife to the boys neck with the robot activating to show it scenes killing intent. The robot is super OP and the boy doesn’t want it on him most of the show.

What is this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875) and see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, when was this? Also don't forget to register your account and take the [tour]!

Comment: I haven't actually read it, but I'm told the character [Jaime Reyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaime_Reyes) from the DC comic strip [*Blue Beetle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Beetle) has an alien scarab permanently attached to his spine which can transform into super-powered armour. He didn't ask for this to happen and at first is very unhappy about it.

Comment: I forgot to say in my previous comment that as well as transforming into armour, the "Blue Beetle" fused to Jaime Reyes' spine acts to protect him against perceived threats whether he wants it to or not.